# Get focused form name

Tags: vb.net

At any given time my application has two open forms, I need to get the form name that is currently being focused for my other code to run. I tried using the code below but it's not working.

```
if Form1.focused = true then
   'process 
elseif form2.focused = true then
   'process
end if
```

Comment: Why is it not working? you do not need the `= true` btw

Comment: Look into `Application.OpenForms` property it contains a collection of all open forms from the application. From there you will have what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use property `Form.ActiveForm`. It will give you a reference to currently active form https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activeform%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
Dim afName As String = Form.ActiveForm.Name
```